# What are the Secondary Stats for In-Vault Dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

**Question**

Everyone knows that each utility room has a S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stat that compliments it (Waterplant-perception, etc). What I want to know is are there secondary stats that are important? Below are examples of secondaries that I'm aware of but I'm paranoid that I'm missing some.

**Examples**

For instance, I train everyone to have high luck because I noticed that it results in better rush-success. Obviously I'm working on my explorers having max luck, so they get the best items.

I put people with a high overall character level near the vault door, because they have more health.

My near-door room is a water plant because everyone in it has maxed perception, for more accurate shooting. Should I also train these near-door protectors in strength, to make them better fighters?

High charisma helps speed up the baby making process. But does it have any effect on happiness if everyone in a room is charismatic?

Does any skill help them put out fires faster?

Maybe high intelligence helps dwellers learn other skills faster?

Does any skill result in children being born with higher starting skill levels?